# EntityFramework Migrations Unable to Update Database, Scaffolds Redundant Migration

Tags: git, entity-framework

Occasionally, when switching between git branches, and then attempting to run the solution (after updating the database by targeting the appropriate migration for the progress of that branch), I receive a database error.

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

As a note, procedure is to have manual migrations.

Anyway, adding a migration via add-migration scaffolds a migration that has actions/content already performed or created in a previous migration, none of which were dropped by a following migration (I checked the database several times to confirm). Upon attempting to update the database to that migration, the console gives an error:

> Column names in each table must be unique....

This confirms that the content is attempting to scaffold is already a part of the database.

Emptying the up and downs and updating to it is moderately useful as a workaround. If another migration is added immediately after doing so, it will be empty, the sign that there's nothing to scaffold.

Typically I can then update the database targeting the last real migration, and delete the empty ones, and it works fine for a while. But if I do anything with git it tends to be undone. The workaround is acceptable but time consuming and annoying. I wish to know if there is a way to stop this from occurring.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I have attempted going down the migration pile until before I started the project and going back up. It didn't help. Also the scaffolding is almost always a copy of another migration line for line (at least recently, anyway).

Comment: i didnt understand...now...your main problem is with EF(and following Errors which you said a but it??) or with git?

Comment: I'm approaching it as if Entity Framework is the most likely cause the problem, but given that the issue props up when switching branches, it could be git related.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how EF generates and executes the migrations might help you to deal with your issues.

EF uses binary model snapshots to determine the incremental changes to be included in scaffolded migrations. Snapshots are stored as part of the code, as embedded resource files with `.resx` extension and the same name as your migration code class. Also, when executing `Update-Database` the snapshot is stored in your current local database. Every time a migration is run a record is inserted in the table `__MigrationsHistory`, and the snapshot is stored in the `Model` column.

Note that the snapshot is not generated from the database actual schema, but from the code in the Model classes. When creating a new migration EF generates on the fly a snapshot of the current Model classes and compares it to the snapshot from the previous migration (again, not to the actual database schema).

When you switch code branches your code gets modified, but your local database doesn't, and there is a risk that the code you get from Git can get out of sync with the snapshots and the contents of `__MigrationsHistory.Model` in your database.

However, even knowing all of that, your problems are not easily explained, assuming that you reverted to a previous common migration. Perhaps you have some manual changes added to your scaffolded migrations, or you did add some `Up` code without the right `Down` code. Or you have different Model code in your branches but you generated migrations with the same name. Or migrations with the same name but different timestamp, so they get duplicated in the `__MigrationsHistory` table. Anyway, once a database gets out of sync with the code migrations it is difficult to restore it back in sync. Usually you will just have to delete it and create it from scratch.

Some advice that might help:

- Check the contents of your `__MigrationsHistory` table before generating new migrations. Make sure the value in the last record in the `MigrationId` column matches the name of your last code migration, timestamp numbers and all. If it doesn't, try to run `Update-Database` with the `-SourceMigration` and `-TargetMigration` parameters to downgrade your database to the right version of the model.
- If you are about to change the code branch and you are going to downgrade your database by running `Update-Database` with an older target migration, do it *before* getting the code of the new branch. You downgrade with the old code, and upgrade with the new one. Downgrading this way deletes the affected records from `__MigrationsHistory`, so you will not keep anything coming from the old model code once you get the new branch code.
- You can also manually delete records from `__MigrationsHistory` to avoid a migration being applied again. But be careful, as the real schema of the database will remain unchanged.

[This msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx) goes into more detail.